# How to add different "title" tags to images within the loop?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to add the post title as a title tag to an image ( that is actually a custom field).
I tried using each() function with no success, but maybe the solution will come from php ?
This is one of the things i tried:

```
$('.front a img').each(function(){
var frontvalue = '<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>';
$(this).attr('title',frontvalue);
});
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: and what is happening? What would you expect?

Comment: It applies the same post title to all of the  images.
And I want that each of the images will get it's relevant title.

Comment: You are echoing a string from the serverside, so that value will be the same in all the iterations. No suprise there ?

Comment: So, are there any other options to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop you can do:

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="<?php echo get_the_title();?>">
```

or with custom field:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "yourCustomFieldName", true);?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>">
```

---

In your specific case, you could remove the last closing bracket and then append the alt property:

```
<?php
$From = substr(trim($From),0,-1);        //cut the last char
$From .= ' alt="'.get_the_title().'">';  //append the title
?>
```

Or even better, extract the url if it's an old type custom field, but don't touch the new type custom fields (which are just the url)

```
if(substr(trim($From),0,5) == '<img '){  //is this an img tag i see?
  $boom = explode('"', $From, 3);        //it is, aim for the quotes
  $From = $boom[1];                      //salvage the url
}
```

and then rebuild your img tag from there. You might wanna read up on [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) if the old format is different from:

```
<img src="xxxxxx">
```

Comment: I can't do that.As I mentioned, I "receive" the image via a custom field, so actually inside the loop there's no image tag but the "key" ($Front in this case).

Comment: Thanks wilks, but it's not gonna work.Sorry, my fault, I assume that if I will post the the code from the loop it will be helpful:
    <?php if($Front !== '') {  echo $Front;  } ?>
when the { echo $Front; } will output as <img src="example.jpg">

Comment: Okay, so how did you declare $From? Is the img tag already in your custom field? I think you'd be better off entering only the image's url , and add the tag later: <?php $From = '<img src="'.$From.'" alt="'.the_title().'">';?>

Comment: Yep, the img tag already in the custom field.You're right, entering the image url only is a good idea, but it causes other problems.There are more than 2,500 published posts using the old method... :/